# ES6 Destructuring on Route render prop parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, jsx

This might be an odd question
But here goes...
I have the following piece of code

```
const About = props => {
  console.log(props.match);
  console.log(props.location);
  console.log(props.history);

  return <div>About</div>;
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
```

And it can be abbreviated with the ES6 object destructuring feature, like this

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route
        path="/about"
        render={({match, location, history}) => {
          console.log(match);
          console.log(location);
          console.log(history);
          return <div>About</div>;
        }}
      />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
```

I am confused about how does the arrow function the render attribute know to extract the 3 properties out from props??

I hope my question makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is merely using JavaScript's [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to destruture the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) parameter in the `render` prop.

As stated in the documentation, the route props is an object consisting of

- [match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)
- [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)
- [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)

This is actually similar to writing it this way:

```
<Route
    path="/about"
    render={(routeProps) => {
      const { match, location, history } = routeProps;
      return <div>About</div>;
    }}
  />
```

Comment: great this actually makes more sense to me. thank you!